# php for loop start with single decimal but required 0 in start

Tags: php

usually php for loop output is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 but i am working in XML RPC code where date is used like 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09

```
for ($i=1; $i<=20; $i++){
  echo "The number is " . $i . "<br />";
  }
```

**out put :**
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20

but my requirement is 
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
for ($i=1; $i<=20; $i++){
  echo "The number is " . str_pad($i,2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT) . "<br />";
  }
```

Comment: This is a PHP programmer. I applaud you, sir!

Answer (score 0):

You could always run some code that will check to see if it's only a single digit (meaning it's under ten)

Something like

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++){
  if($i < 10) :
    echo "The number is " . '0' . $i . "<br />";
  else:
    echo echo "The number is " . $i . "<br />";
  endif;
}
```

I used the [syntactic sugar](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/286769-php-syntactic-sugar/) for my `if` statement, but you can just as easily replace the colons with curly braces! Hope that helps!

Comment: :( is there any native php rather than if else ?

Comment: Yeah. There's an answer below! I'm not that well versed in PHP! Sorry D:

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) to Pad the numbers from 1-9 with 0

```
$value = $i;
if ($i < 10) {
$value = str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo "The number is " . $value  . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [printf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php):

```
 for ( $i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++ ){
     printf( "The number is %02u <br />\n", $i );
 }
```

The 02 specifies the minimum number (2) of leading characters ("0"). If you end up needing more leading zeros, just change the number. I think this is most readable syntax.